# Lady first or Ladies first?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am wondering whether we should always say "Ladies first" no matter how many women there are. Or

can we say "Lady first" to express our politeness when there is only one woman?

Comment: Remember to only use this is an ironic, post-feminist manner these days. Some people will take offence at you discriminating in this way [Nope, you can't win, whatever you do.]

Answer (score 5):

It's always **Ladies first**.  It is expressing a general principle - *ladies* should go first - not referring to any specific lady or ladies.